# CSP error in a node.js application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, content-security-policy

I've a node.js application with a home page in angularjs. This page contains a 'search' box and has corresponding search.js script which runs and makes a server side query call. For security I added 'csp' in my node.js application with following csp configuration.

```
const csp = require('helmet-csp');
app.use(helmet());
app.use(csp({
directives: {
  defaultSrc: ["'self'", 'https://my.domain.com'],
  scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
  styleSrc: ["'self'"],
  imgSrc: ["'self'"],
  connectSrc: ["'self'"],
  fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https://fonts.googleapis.com'],
  objectSrc: ["'none'"],
  mediaSrc: ["'self'"],
  frameSrc: ["'none'"],
},
setAllHeaders: false, // set to true if you want to set all headers
safari5: false // set to true if you want to force buggy CSP in Safari 5
}));
```

But with this change, I started getting following errors in chrome browser.

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800|Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'".

prefixfree.min.js:17 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I don't understand what these error means. How do I fix these errors. I need to use fonts from google as part of my style.css file which has following entry,

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800|Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700);
```

Is this right way to set csp? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess the message it's pretty clear. style-src 'self' doesn't allow this style to be applied, and you need to add 'unsafe-inline',

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the address to googleapis was flagged due to csp policy. I solved this problem by,

1. downloaded required fonts from Google webfonts helper site
2. removed @import from CSS
3. removed googleapis from fontSrc and kept only "'self'" instead.